# How to run python files without using terminal or gui?

Tags: python, py2exe, file-extension

Hello gyus i have started python and i want to know how can i excecute python file without using terminal.Just like the most games using (exe) file extension but for py files.I have tried py2exe but it doesn't show anything on the screen. I tried to make excecutable the py file with no luck. Please tell me how to excecute the and if there is an option whithout using a specific program for that.

My system is : Windows 7 / Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Would this help? http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-475163.html

Comment: At which stage of trying `py2exe` did you get a blank screen? On Windows, this is probably your best bet (although you can associate `.py` files with Python if you have updated your `PATH`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, have a look in my blog, It explains how ca you do it in Ubuntu.

http://insidepython.wordpress.com/2012/08/04/hello-world-or-how-or-say-ni/

but basically:

Add this line to the beginning of your script

```
#!<location of your python interpreter>
```

To find out where your python interpreter is installed:

$ sudo find / -name "python"

After executing the previous, you should get the location of your python interpreter, then you need to set the environment variable, in my case python executable is located in /usr/bin/python

$ export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/python"

Then you need to set the file attributes to executable, you can look more into file attributes in Unix/Linux here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

$ chmod +x shrubbery.py

And finally to execute your application

$ ./shrubbery.py

Comment: For windows I don't know how to do it sorry

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, there's also a python script called GUI2Exe that I have used in the past to create distributable versions of python scripts as apps. It's available at 
http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/ and is, in my opinion, very simple to use. Tutorials and whatnot are easy to find on Google.

It uses py2exe (or any other Python compiler library) to put together the script, but it doesn't require any syntactically annoying setup.py file.